# regex in python, remove pattern '[.../...]' from the string in python

Tags: python, regex, string

I have an input string for e.g:

input_str = 'this is a test for [blah] and [blah/blahhhh]'

and I want to retain [blah] but want to remove [blah/blahhhh] from the above string.
I tried the following codes:

```
>>>re.sub(r'\[.*?\]', '', input_str)
'this is a test for  and '
```

and

```
>>>re.sub(r'\[.*?\/.*?\]', '', input_str)
'this is a test for '
```

what should be the right regex pattern to get the output as "this is a test for [blah] and"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why your 2nd regex doesn't work, I tested it yes, you are correct, it doesn't work. So you can use the same idea but with different approaches.

Instead of using the wildcards you can use the `\w` like this:

```
\[\w+\/\w+\]
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/UA9n5v/1)**

By the way, if you can have non characters separated by `/`, then you can use this regex:

```
\[[^\]]*\/[^\]]*]
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/UA9n5v/2)**

Comment: Won't work if there is any non-word character in the brackets (such as space).

Comment: @DYZ, thanks for the comment. Yes, I know but OP seems to have a tag thing. Let's see what OP thinks. Btw, did you downvote?

Comment: @DYZ, I posted another regex too in case OP has non word characters

Comment: The OP is not specific on what the characters are. The solution has to make no assumptions, either.

Comment: @DYZ, you can't assume the opposite either. Can you? Anyway, as I said, I posted a 2nd regex for your thought

Comment: In fact, one should assume the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the second regex in the original post matches more than the OP wants is that `.` matches any character including `]`.  So `\[.*?\/'` (or just `\[.*?/` since the `\` before the `/` is superfluous) will match more than it seems the OP wanted: `[blah] and [blah/` in `input_str`.

The `?` adds confusion.  It will limit repetition of the `.*` part of `.*\]` sub-expression, but you have to understand what repetition you're limiting [1].  It's better to explicitly match any non-closing bracket instead of the `.` wildcard to begin with.  So-called "greedy" matching of `.*` is often a stumbling block since it will match zero or more occurrences of *any* character until that wildcard match fails (usually much longer than people expect).  In your case it greedily matches as much of the input as possible until the *last* occurrence of the next explicitly specified part of the regex (`]` or `/` in your regexes).  Instead of using `?` to try to counteract or limit greedy matching with lazy matching, it is often better to be explicit about what to not match in the greedy part.

As an illustration, see the following example of `.*` grabbing everything until the *last* occurrence of the character after `.*`:

```
echo '////k////,/k' | sed -r 's|/.*/|XXX|'
XXXk

echo '////k////,/k' | sed -r 's|/(.*)?/|XXX|'
XXXk
```

And subtleties of greedy / lazy matching behavior can vary from one regex implementation to the next (pcre, python, grep/egrep).  For portability and simplicity / clarity, be explicit when you can.

If you only want to look for strings with brackets that don't include a closing bracket character before the slash character, you could more explicitly look for "not-a-closing-bracket" instead of the wildcard match:

```
re.sub(r'\[[^]]*/[^]]*\]', '', input_str)
'this is a test for [blah] and '
```

This uses a character class expression - `[^]]` - instead of the wildcard `.` to match any character that is explicitly not a closing bracket.

If it's "legal" in your input stream to have one or more closing brackets within enclosing brackets (before the slash), then things get more complicated since you have to determine if it's just a stray bracket character or the start of a nested sub-expression.  That's starting to sound more like the job of a token parser.

Depending on what you are trying to really achieve (I assume this is just a dummy example of something that is probably more complex) and what is allowed in the input, you may need something more than my simple modification above.  But it works for your example anyway.

[1] http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Answer (score -1):

You can write a function that takes that input_str as an argument and loop trough the string and if it sees '/' between '[' and ']' jumps back to the position where '[' is and removes all elements including ']'